# ipyleaflet Search Control never successfully searches

Tags: python, ipywidgets, ipyleaflet

I've followed the [examples](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/examples/SearchControl.ipynb) but I can never get the ipyleaflet `SearchControl` to work in my JupyterLab notebook:

```py
import json
from ipyleaflet import Map, GeoJSON, SearchControl, LayerGroup

m = Map(center=(40, -100), zoom=10)
data = {}
#  fill data as {'layer': GeoDataFrame}

search_space = LayerGroup()

for layer in data:
    search_space.add_layer(
        GeoJSON(data=json.loads(data[layer].to_json(drop_id=True)))
    ) #  `data[layer]` is a geopandas GeoDataFrame

m.add_control(SearchControl(
    position = 'topleft',
    layer = search_space,
))
```

Even when I grab the same [JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/master/examples/countries.geo.json) used in [the docs](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls/search_control.html), I still suffer the error that no search term is ever found.

Additionally, I've noticed the map populates with unclickable markers when I attach the controls to map. These markers align with the locations from my data. So something is happening, but it is certainly wrong behavior.

Running ipyleaflet 0.17.0 on Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no idea what `property_name` did because it was undocumented. I created [a PR](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/pull/1031) to fix it.